# Получения значения по ключу

Tags: java, java-hashmap

В общем стоит довольно таки тривиальная задача, получения значения по ключу из HashMap или TreeMap (до сих пор не знаю для этой задачи лучше использовать хеш или три мап).

```
char[] decode = {'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'D',
        'D', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'B'}; //это у нас массив который будем сравнивать с ключём в HashMap

HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        Set<Map.Entry<String,Object>> entrySet=map.entrySet();
        map.put("A", "11");
        map.put("B", "01");
        map.put("C", "10");
        map.put("D", "00"); //тут мы заполнили наш HashMap ключем и значением
String encode = ""; //пустой стринг, куда будем записывать наши значения полученные по ключу
Object desiredObject=new Object();
desiredObject=decode; //тут мы приравниваем объекту массив, который будем сравнивать с ключем в хешмапе
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> pair : entrySet) {
if (desiredObject.equals(pair.getKey())) {
    encode=encode+pair.getValue();// нашли наше значение и возвращаем  значение
}
```

}

Честно признаюсь подобный код нашёл на просторах интернета и якобы правильный при таких операциях, только вот мой `String` остается всегда пустым. Изначально у меня была идея сделать обычное сравнение через двумерный цикл, как это делается с обычными массивами и списками, но в Java так просто это не работает.

Пример ответа в стринг должен быть примерно таким (11 01 00 01 00 ...) то есть все найденные значения по заданному ключу записаться в тот пустой стринг

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    char[] decode = {'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'D',
        'D', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'B'}; //это у нас массив который будем сравнивать с ключём в HashMap

    Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('A', "11");
    map.put('B', "01");
    map.put('C', "10");
    map.put('D', "00"); 
    StringBuilder encode = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (char ch : decode) {
        String get = map.get(ch);
        if (get!=null) encode.append(get);
    }

    System.out.println(encode.toString());
```

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то из массива чаров вы пытаетесб получить 0 и 1, которые соотвествуют этим чарам в мапе. тогда это выглядит так

Comment: Да, правильно поняли. В общем спасибо за ответ, все работает как нужно